# Problem with integer comparison using indexOf

Tags: java, android, indexof

I need to read a text from the web. I load the page inside a string and search for the word "blue". The problem is that even if indexOf returns -1, the code considers > 0. Has anyone had this problem?

```
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                if (str.indexOf("blue") > 0 ) {
                   // It always stops here, even if it doesn't have the word "blue"
                }
            }
```

Comment: "*The problem is that even if indexOf returns -1*" - [Cannot reproduce (`ideone.com`)](https://ideone.com/38B6Dn). How did you verified that `str.indexOf("blue")` is `-1`?

Comment: Btw: If "blue" can also be at the beginning of str, your if-statement wouldn't catch it (because indexOf would return 0). Consider changing to `str.contains("blue")`.

Comment: That, or use `>= 0` instead of `> 0`.

Comment: Thank you for answer.

1) I verified if > 0, doesn't work.

2) I tried contains, and not work.

3) I tried >= 0, and not work.

Thank you again

Comment: But, *How* did you verify `if (str.indexOf("blue") > 0 )` doesn't work? I suggest you try something like this: `System.out.println (">" + str + "<"); if (str.indexOf("blue") > 0) { System.out.println ("It worked!"); ... } else { System.out.println ("It didn't work"); ...}`

Comment: *// It always stops here* Meaning *blocks*?

Comment: Also if it's an html page it is not valid to read lines unless in a context of `<pre>` tags (or 'modern equivalent'). You should use instead an html parser or you could at a pinch read the lot into a string if you know the content encoding.

Comment: I think that's the problem. I am reading a web page html. I will need to convert this string. Thank you

Comment: You didn't answer my question...

Comment: Sorry gOOse. I tried, but doesn't work too. The problem is a string with html code.

Comment: My question was about the meaning of the comment you posted. Also it might help if you show us the url you're using